# Problem when using keycloak roles authorization with cdi scope

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, cdi, keycloak

I´m trying to set up a jax-rs endpoing using keycloak role authorization and cdi `@requestscoped` annotation, but doing so the `@rolesallowed` and `@denyall` annotations on the class or methods are simply ignored.

```java
// dont work
@RequestScoped
@RolesAllowed("admin")
@Path("/helloworld")
public class Test
```

```java
//work
@Stateless
@RolesAllowed("admin")
@Path("/helloworld")
public class Test
```

If i change `@requestscoped` for `@stateless` it works and the security annotations are considered.

Can anyone elaborate on that?